# JFileChooser seems to be running, but not showing

Tags: java, visibility, jfilechooser

I'm trying to create a program that involves the use of JFileChooser so that a user may give the program a file's path for manipulation. When I attempt to launch the JFileChooser, nothing appears and the programs pauses (or rather it seems that it is pausing). I feel that the JFileChooser *is* running, but not showing up graphically. I'm even getting a Java program icon in my application tray when it runs, something I only get when I run graphical programs. I've clicked it and checked for available windows under the running application, but there are none. I  have no idea why this is the case. My code, even though it's very similar to that of tutorials I've found online, is:

```
final JFileChooser userFile = new JFileChooser();
int response = userFile.showOpenDialog(null);
if (response == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
   fileName = userFile.getSelectedFile().toString();
else
   fileName = "The file open operation failed.";
```

MCVE:

```
import lots of stuff;

public class zipCracker {

    private static String fileName;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String[] buttons = {"Cancel", "zDictionaryForm", "zZipCracker"};

        int rc = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,
                                              "Which program would you like to use?",
                                              "Program Directory",
                                              JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE,
                                              0, null, buttons, buttons[0]);
        if(rc == 2)
            zZipCracker();
        else if(rc == 1)
            System.exit(0);
        else
            System.exit(0);
    }

    public static String zZipCracker(){
        final JFileChooser userFile = new JFileChooser();
        int response = userFile.showOpenDialog(null);
        if (response == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
            fileName = userFile.getSelectedFile().toString();
        else
            fileName = "The file open operation failed.";


        //ZipFile zipper = new ZipFile(userFile);
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: If you don't get help soon, consider creating and posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example Program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) where you condense your code into the smallest bit that still compiles and runs, has no outside dependencies (such as need to link to a database or images), has no extra code that's not relevant to your problem, but still demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Also, is your program a Swing GUI? Or is it a console program? If a Swing GUI, consider using a non-null parameter for your `showOpenDialog(...)` method call. If a non-Swing console program, then you will need to be sure that you create and show your dialog on a Swing event thread.

Comment: It's supposed to be utilizing Swing. From what I gathered from the documentation page from Oracle, providing the `null` parameter should just make it pop up in the center of the screen. I've tried creating a JFrame that takes up the entire screen and setting the parent for `showOpenDialog(parent)` to the JFrame, but I still get nothing.

Comment: OK, then show us your [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please. You've likely got a bug in code not shown, so you'll either have to do some debugging to find the bug, or else show us enough code, but a reasonable amount of code, code that compiles and runs, and that demonstrates for us your problem.

Comment: I added my entire class because there is little to see. I'm not sure if I'm supposed to explicitly state that the JFileChooser should be visible or what.

Comment: Your code works for me --  I do see the file chooser dialog. Note that your program as written is not really a Swing GUI, but rather is a command line program that shows two dialog windows.

Comment: It works for me, `JFileChooser` may take several seconds to load, you might need to give it some time...

Comment: I'm on OS X, if that has anything to do with it (though I highly doubt it since everything else works just fine). I started the program and left it open for two minutes with no luck. Is there any way to use the native OS X file viewer to select the file instead of using the Java one that won't load?

Comment: Try and make sure you  are stating the UI within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread, see [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) for more details

Comment: Weirdly, it works just fine if I call the exact same code in the `main` method. Does the link you've provided relate to the UI being run in a separate method?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that making the JFileChooser object global, private, and static solved my issue. I have no idea where the difference between declaring it in the method and declaring it globally is, but it works.

```
import stuff;

public class zipCracker {

    private static String fileName;
    private static JFileChooser userFile = new JFileChooser(); //now declared globally

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String[] buttons = {"Cancel", "zDictionaryForm", "zZipCracker"};

        int rc = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,
                                              "Which program would you like to use?",
                                              "Program Directory",
                                              JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE,
                                              0, null, buttons, buttons[0]);
        System.out.println(rc);
        if(rc == 2)
            zZipCracker();
        else if(rc == 1)
            System.exit(0);
        else
            System.exit(0);
    }

    public static String zZipCracker(){
        int returnVal = userFile.showDialog(null, "Choose This"); //used without being declared here in the method
        if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
            fileName = userFile.getSelectedFile().toString();
        else
            fileName = "The file open operation failed.";


        //ZipFile zipper = new ZipFile(userFile);
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was stuck on this issue for hours, I don't know why making it an attribute makes a difference though

Comment: Making it `static` didn't solve the problem for me. In fact my program just freezes at startup now instead of when I try to open the dialog.